# From a dotnet solution how can I know what packages are installed from a package source?

Tags: visual-studio, ide, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

I have a dotnet solution,
where I had to associate multiple package sources. As an example:
[image]
Now when I build the solution it installs the packages, but I want to know their package source origin after they are installed.
What is the best way to do it?

I already tried to run a command like:

```
while((Get-Project -All | Get-Package).Length -gt 0) { Get-Project -All | Get-Package | Uninstall-Package }
```

which doesn't seem ideal because it removes the packages references for .csproj then I need to add them again in that file (I can just discard change since I use git)

Now I do a rebuild on the solution and if I uncheck all package sources it builds... Which is not my expected result because it shouldn't have any source to pull the packages.

Another thing I noticed is that when I go to
**Manage Packages for Solution** section in Visual Studio some packages Installed appear with

[image]